# Change h2 with onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript. I need help getting on with my code. Right now, the font and color in `label_1` and `label_2` are changing. I want only `h2` to change color and font which is under the div class `task-box`. How should I proceed?

```js
function swap_color_and_font() {
  document.getElementById("label_1").style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById("label_2").style.fontFamily = "courier ";
}
```

```html
<div class="task_box">
  <h2>Change font and color</h2>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="font_color" id="label_1" </label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="font_color" value="" /><br/>
      <label for="font_color" id="label_2" </label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="font_family" value="" /><br/>
      <input onclick="swap_color_and_font()" value="Change font and color" type="button" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hi, Where you have defined label_1 and label_2?

Comment: Now is the correct code entered

Comment: Check your html you have some errors

Answer (score 2):

Here is an HTML and js comprehension mistake.
First, use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) because it's way easily and maintainable.

`document.querySelector()` take a string parameter which is an identifier like CSS use.

So here we want to change our h2 tag, place "h2" in param.
*Maybe it could be better to use HTML id (refer to tutorials)*

And btw, don't use `<br>` tags like this. Prefer to use CSS (refer to tutorial)

```js
// Here your javascript code should be in script tags if it's not in an other document 

  function swap_color_and_font() {
    document.querySelector("h2").style.color = "red";
    document.querySelector("h2").style.fontFamily = "courier ";
  }
```

```html
<div class="task_box">
  <h2>Change font and color</h2>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
  <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

  <form>
    <!-- apply css rules on fieldset like : display: flex; flex-direction: column; -->
    <fieldset>
      <label for="font_color">Font color</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="font_color" value="" /><br/>
      <label for="font_family">Font</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="font_family" value="" /><br/>
      <input onclick="swap_color_and_font()" value="Change font and color" type="button" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if I have more h2 in my code and want all h2 to change, how do I do that?

Comment: replace `document.querySelector()` by `document.querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 0):

There are some broken tags in your HTML and your Javascript isn't in script tags.
You can add a 'id' to your h2 element and select it with 'getElementById' or use the 'querySelector' function. Make sure to properly close your 'task_box' div.
Here is an fixed example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stackoverflow Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="task_box"> <!-- Start of div class with classname 'task_box' -->
        <h2 id="h2-with-id">Change font and color</h2>              
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>                 
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

        <form> 
            <fieldset>
                <!-- Make sure to properly define the label tags -->
                <label for="font_color" id="label_1">Label 1</label><br/>
                <input type="text" id="font_color" value=""/><br/>
                <label for="font_color" id="label_2">Label 2</label><br/>
                <input type="text" id="font_family" value=""/><br/>
                <input onclick="swap_color_and_font()" value="Change font and color" type="button"/>
            </fieldset> 
        </form>
    </div> <!-- End of div class with classname 'task_box' -->

    <div class="task_box">
        <h2>Second H2</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- Create a Script tag to add Javascript code in document -->
    <script> 
        function swap_color_and_font() { 
            // Get Element By ID 
            document.getElementById("h2-with-id").style.color="red";
            
            // Get Element by Query Selection (Select all h2 elements within the class 'task_box')
            document.querySelector(".task_box h2").style.fontFamily="courier";

            // Loop trough all h2 elements that are in classes 'task_box'
            var allH2Elements = document.querySelectorAll(".task_box h2");
            allH2Elements.forEach(function(h2Element) {
                h2Element.style.color="red";
                h2Element.style.fontFamily="courier";
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if I have more "tast_box" and h2 in my code and want all h2 to change, how do I do that?

Comment: I've updated the example with a call to 'querySelectorAll' which gives back a list of found elements. You can loop through them and change styles. 

'getElementById' should only find one exact element.
'querySelector' finds the first element that matches.
'querySelectorAll' finds all that match.